# ALTER INDEX using while Loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, indexing

I am trying to `ALTER` the index using while loop.

The below code gets all the INDEX STATEMENTS which is greater than 30% Fragmentation. Stored into a TEMP table.

I am trying to use while loop to do the iteration and execute each ALTER STATEMENT.

Note: I do not want to use Cursor.

```
WITH resultset AS
(
    SELECT
        DB_NAME() AS 'DB Name',
        dbtables.[name] AS 'Table Name',
        dbindexes.[name] AS 'Index Name',
        indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent as '% Fragmented',
        indexstats.page_count as 'Page Count',
        'Query' = case when avg_fragmentation_in_percent between 10 and 29.99 then 'ALTER INDEX '+dbindexes.[name] +' ON '+dbtables.[name]+' REBUILD'
when avg_fragmentation_in_percent  >= 30 then 'ALTER INDEX '+dbindexes.[name] +' ON '+dbtables.[name]+' REBUILD' end
    FROM 
        sys.DM_DB_INDEX_PHYSICAL_STATS(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables dbtables ON dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.schemas dbschemas ON dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
                                 AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
     WHERE 
         dbindexes.name IS NOT NULL
         AND dbtables.Temporal_type <> 1
         AND indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 30
)
SELECT * 
INTO #FragmentationTable 
FROM resultset

DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT
DECLARE @execute  nvarchar(500)
SELECT @ROWCOUNT= COUNT(1)  FROM #FragmentationTable
SELECT @ROWCOUNT

DECLARE @cnt INT = 0 ;

WHILE @cnt < @ROWCOUNT
BEGIN
   select @execute=query  from #FragmentationTable
    --EXEC sp_executesql @execute
    print @execute
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
PRINT 'THIS IS OUTSIDE OF THE LOOP'
DROP TABLE #FragmentationTable
```

The output comes like this. Its altering only one index.

[image]

Comment: Why would you expect `select @execute=query  from #FragmentationTable` to return a different row each time? You somehow have to tell SQL Server you already processed the "first" row in order for it to move on to the 2nd (you'll need a row number for that, either to identify the _next_ row, or to delete the row you just processed). Alternatively, instead of building 80 commands and stuffing them into a table, executing them one at a time, why not build a single batch of 80 commands and execute it once?

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over a table, use a cursor.  That's what they're for.

And always escape object names with the QUOTENAME function when constructing dynamic SQL.  eg

```
WITH resultset AS
(
    SELECT
        DB_NAME() AS 'DB Name',
        dbtables.[name] AS 'Table Name',
        dbindexes.[name] AS 'Index Name',
        indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent as '% Fragmented',
        indexstats.page_count as 'Page Count',
        'Query' = case when avg_fragmentation_in_percent between 10 and 29.99 then 'ALTER INDEX '+quotename(dbindexes.[name]) +' ON '+quotename(dbtables.[name])+' REBUILD'
when avg_fragmentation_in_percent  >= 30 then 'ALTER INDEX '+quotename(dbindexes.[name]) +' ON '+quotename(dbtables.[name])+' REBUILD' end
    FROM 
        sys.DM_DB_INDEX_PHYSICAL_STATS(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables dbtables ON dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.schemas dbschemas ON dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
                                 AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
     WHERE 
         dbindexes.name IS NOT NULL
         AND dbtables.Temporal_type <> 1
         AND indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 30
)
SELECT * 
INTO #FragmentationTable 
FROM resultset

declare c cursor local for 
  select query
  from #FragmentationTable

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

open c
fetch next from c into @sql
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    print @sql
    fetch next from c into @sql
END;
close c;
deallocate c;
PRINT 'THIS IS OUTSIDE OF THE LOOP'
DROP TABLE #FragmentationTable
```